# Python: Bug in my code is moving a folder into another folder and I have no clue why

Tags: python

This piece of the code I've been working on in order to organize my Downloads on my PC is causing me a lot of trouble. What the rest of the code does is examine the file extension of the file and put the file in a relevant folder then, however folders don't have extensions so I had to create this function. The problem is that each time I run with a 5 minute gap, it removes on of the last folders in the downloads and moves it into the folders folder.

```
   extension = ['jpg', 'exe', 'ico', 'png','webm', 'gif', 'iso', 'txt', 'psd', 'wmv', 'mp4','xlsx','doc','msi','m4v','wav','mkv','rar','mid','mp3','zip','epub', 'folders']

   def move_folders(extensions):
        list_of_folders = os.listdir(".")
        new_list = list_of_folders
        common = [i for i in list_of_folders if i in extensions]
        for n in range(0,len(common)-1):
            for m in range(0,len(list_of_folders)-1):
                if common[n] == list_of_folders[m]:
                    del list_of_folders[m]
        if os.path.isdir('/Users/Jan-Hendrik/Downloads/folders') == False:
            os.mkdir("folders")        
        for folder in list_of_folders:
            dest_folder = '/Users/Jan-Hendrik/Downloads/folders/%s' % folder
            dest_folder_main = '/Users/Jan-Hendrik/Downloads/folders'        
            if os.path.exists(dest_folder) == True and os.path.exists(dest_folder_main) == True:
                os.remove(folder)
                try:
                    log = open("log.txt",'r+')
                except IOError:
                    log = open("log.txt", "w")
                log.write("%s removed at %s " % (n, str(time.asctime(time.gmtime()))))
                log.write("")
                log.close()
            elif folder != "log.txt" and folder != "DownloadFolderMove.py":
                move_files(folder, "folders")
            else:
                pass
```

Before and after to see what I mean above.

Before: http://prntscr.com/52sa1w
After: http://prntscr.com/52sabe

Comment: looks like some debugging is required

Comment: what exactly do you want to happen to the folders?

Comment: You're subtracting 1 manually in your `range` calls, which suggests you *may* be overlooking the fact that `range(0, n)` iterates over the numbers from 0 to `n-1`,  not 0 to `n`  (can't be sure though, because it's unclear to me what you're trying to do).    Also,  `open( filename, "a" )` may be what you want, to avoid the awkward `try...except IOError...` construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this piece of code

```
list_of_folders = os.listdir(".")
new_list = list_of_folders
common = [i for i in list_of_folders if i in extensions]
for n in range(0,len(common)-1):
     for m in range(0,len(list_of_folders)-1):
          if common[n] == list_of_folders[m]:
               del list_of_folders[m]
```

This removes all the items from `list_of_folders` except "zip". In general, deleting items from a list while looping through the same list will lead to trouble. Your list is getting shorter but the programme continues iterating through the range of indexes that you set at the beginning of the loop (`len(list_of_folders)-1`). You also wrongly set the range to the length of the list minus one, so that the only one remaining is the last in the list. This is why the last folder in your directory gets removed.

You can replace the above with

```
list_of_folders = [folder for folder in os.listdir('.') if folder not in extensions]
```

or alternatively rewrite your function as follows, which I think is more readable.

```
def move_folders(extensions):
    for folder in os.listdir('.'):
        if os.path.isdir(folder) and folder not in extensions:
            if os.path.exists(os.path.join('folders', folder)):
                os.remove(folder)
                try:
                    log = open("log.txt",'r+')
                except IOError:
                    log = open("log.txt", "w")
                log.write("{} removed at {}".format(folder, time.asctime(time.gmtime())))
                log.write("")
                log.close()
            else: 
                move_files(folder, "folders")
```

(I'm assuming you only want this to apply to folders so have added the condition `os.path.isdir`)